# How to bulk create many sites using one platform in Aegir

Tags: drush, aegir

I a plan to use [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/) (part of a [BOA](https://github.com/omega8cc/boa) server) to host many sales sites, one site for one product.

I would like to know how to bulk-create 1000 sites using an existing platform in Aegir.

This apparently is not included in the [Aegir handbook](http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/)

If it may be more efficient, the other approach would be to clone 1000 sites from one existing site in Aegir.

I suppose that this can be accomplished either way using Drush, but how?
It should use a list of domain names.

Answer (score 1):

I've used software-as-a-service modules before to test this. This is what I use because I worked on/with these modules a lot so it's the most efficient route for me, but I don't think it would take anyone more than an hour to set up.

(This is a clone-based approach.)

Go to your hostmaster site and download the important modules:

```
drush dl hosting_variables hosting_saas
git clone --branch no-specifics https://github.com/PraxisLabs/hosting_restapi.git
```

Enable the modules, and set the site nid and platform nid in Hosting -> SaaS. (You can find the nid of a site or platform in the URL of their "edit" tab.)

Test the site creation with this bash command:

```
curl --data "url=test1.example.com&invoice=1" http://yourhostmasterurl/hosting/api/site
```

If this works, from there you can easily create 1000 sites with a simple bash script:

```
for ((i=2;i<=1000;i++));
do
   curl --data "url=test$i.example.com&invoice=$i" http://yourhostmasterurl/hosting/api/site
done
```

This would queue up clone creation for test2.example to test1000.example.com

[Here's an article](https://praxis.coop/en/blog/automated-drupal-saas-aegir3) I wrote on using Aegir SaaS in production.

Alternatively, you can set up [Hosting Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_services) and use the REST API to queue up site creation tasks. I think this could take a few hours if you've never used it before.

Comment: what version of BOA/Aegir needs to be used for this SaaS setup? I'm currently using the recent [version BOA-3.0.1]

Comment: Site creation test is not working: this is the command line output: see http://i.imgur.com/WpOWVxD.png

Comment: Each 'product site' has its own unique domain name, not a subdomain so the cloning feature should read the domain names from a provided list in a file. The site names are the same as the domain names. Is that possible ?

Comment: I use standard Aegir 3.4. I don't know how BOA interferes with this, could be due to nginx but I doubt it (I've mostly tested this on Apache).

(Sorry I didn't see this in time, simpler to just follow up on drupal.org)

Comment: I don't have permission to comment on the above blog post, but most of the code necessary has recently been merged into [Aegir SaaS](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_services) (now a submodule of Aegir Services) and refined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Drush is your friend here.

Examples from [the import handbook](http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/usage/sites/importing/#importing-a-single-site-manually) and [context import](http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/extend/provision/#importing-contexts-into-the-front-end) should be helpful.

There once was a [feeds integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/aegir_feeds) to create sites based uppon cvs or rss. But it has not been updated for Aegir 3.x.

Updates to the docs pages are always welcome ;)